# OpenLayers GetFeature Control Mobile

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, mobile, getfeature

I have a map that is using OpenLayers and GeoServer. I have a base layer and a WMS layer with many features. I was using `OpenLayers.Control.Click` to get the coordinates from the map and show a popup about the closest feature on the WMS layer.

This worked some of the time but it didn't always bring up the popup for the selected point. When it did work, though, it worked on desktop and mobile. So I changed to `OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature`. This works great on the desktop but doesn't respond at all on mobile.

Can I get it to work on mobile?